# DBIx Migration not recognising MySQL

Tags: mysql, perl, database-migration, dbix-class

I'm trying to follow along this tutorial using MySQL:
https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Migration::Tutorial::FirstMigration

I'm running the commands it states with the additional option `--database MySQL`.

Example:

`dbic-migration -I lib/ -I local/lib/perl5/ --S Database::Main --target_dir share/ --database MySQL prepare`

`dbic-migration -I lib/ -I local/lib/perl5/ --S Database::Main --target_dir share/ --database MySQL install`

However when doing the install command, it gives me the following output:

```
$ dbic-migration -I lib/ -I local/lib/perl5/ --S Database::Main --target_dir share/ --database MySQL install

Since this database is not versioned, we will assume version 1
Reading configurations from share/fixtures/1/conf
Can't opendir($fh, 'share/migrations/SQLite/deploy/1'): No such file or directory at local/lib/perl5/DBIx/Class/DeploymentHandler/DeployMethod/SQL/Translator.pm line 109
DBIx::Class::Storage::TxnScopeGuard::DESTROY(): A DBIx::Class::Storage::TxnScopeGuard went out of scope without explicit commit or error. Rolling back. at local/lib/perl5/DBIx/Class/DeploymentHandler/DeployMethod/SQL/Translator.pm line 116
```

My `share` directory looks as follows:

```
└── share
    ├── database-main.db
    ├── fixtures
    │   └── 1
    │       └── conf
    │           └── all_tables.json
    └── migrations
        ├── MySQL
        │   └── deploy
        │       └── 1
        │           ├── 001-auto-__VERSION.sql
        │           └── 001-auto.sql
        ├── _common
        │   └── deploy
        │       └── 1
        │           └── 002-demo.pl
        └── _source
            └── deploy
                └── 1
                    ├── 001-auto-__VERSION.yml
                    └── 001-auto.yml
```

Is anyone aware of why it is continuing to look for the SQLite directory when I have specified MySQL?

Comment: I also wanted to ask; is using the `dbic-migration` command the same as using `DBIx::Class::DeploymentHandler` within a script that will upgrade/downgrade/install/populate the database?

Answer (score 0):

[Reading the docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DBIx-Class-Migration/lib/DBIx/Class/Migration/Script/Help/prepare.pod), my suspicion is dbic-migration is using this pattern...

```
dbic-migration <generic options> <command> <options for that command>
```

[The docs back this up](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Migration::Tutorial::FirstMigration#Using-the-dbic-migration-commandline-tool)...

> dbic-migration is your main gateway to managing your migrations. When using the tool you will give it one command (such as version above) and any number of option flags (starting with -- or -).

If you say...

```
dbic-migration --database MySQL prepare
```

`--database MySQL` will be ignored because it's not a known general option for dbic-migration.

You must say...

```
dbic-migration prepare --database MySQL
```

In which `--database MySQL` is understood to be an option of the prepare command.

It is unfortunate that it does not warn you about options it does not understand.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i've tried `dbic-migration -I lib/ -I local/lib/perl5/ --S Database::Main --target_dir share/ install --database MySQL` but that still seems to be looking for the SQLite directory. Do you think it would be a good idea to instead make scripts to upgrade/downgrade/install the database?

Comment: @a7omiton I would try putting everything but the -I options after the command.  `dbic-migration -I lib/ -I local/lib/perl5/ prepare ...all the options...` and `dbic-migration  -I lib/ -I local/lib/perl5/ install ..all the options..`.

Comment: I'm getting ahead with using scripts to install and upgrade schema, just a matter of how to make sure i don't mess with the data already existing i.e. not delete everything! ;)